# set theory question in ZF

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A and B infinite sets and |A|<=|B|. Is that equivalent to |P(A)|<=|P(B)| in ZF?
P denotes the powerset.
I think it is equivalent, but I dont know exactly how to prove it.

Comment: Not even in $\sf ZFC$. This question has been asked more than several times.

Comment: Note that the case of equality is sufficient here, since now $\kappa<\lambda$ and $2^\kappa=2^\lambda$. Then indeed we have that $\kappa\leq\lambda$, but we also have that $\lambda\nleq\kappa$, but $2^\kappa=2^\lambda$.

Comment: Oops! Thanks @Asaf, for making explicit what already was explicit (yet I somehow failed to catch!)

Comment: Thanks Asaf for your help!